# Selenium data-driven testing: Null pointer Exception

Tags: java, selenium, data-driven-tests

Hi there i was following a tutorial regarding the data driven testing in selenium and i want to read data from the excel file .xlsx but its giving me null pointer.

**Below is the code:**

```
    package com.usman;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;public class ReadDataFromExcelSheet {




    public String[][] getExcelData(String excellocation, String sheetName) {
        try {
            String dataSets[][] = null;
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(excellocation));

            // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
            // count number of active rows
            int totalRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            // count number of active columns in row
            int totalColumn = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            // Create array of rows and column
            dataSets = new String[totalRow][totalColumn];
            // Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            int i = 0;
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(i);

                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                // For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                int j = 0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    if (cell.getStringCellValue().contains("User Name")) {
                        break;
                    }

                    // Check the cell type and format accordingly
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        dataSets[i - 1][j++] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        dataSets[i - 1][j++] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        dataSets[i - 1][j++] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                        dataSets[i - 1][j++] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    }

                }

                System.out.println("");
                i++;
            }
            file.close();
            return dataSets;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void updateResult(String excellocation, String sheetName, String testCaseName, String testStatus) throws IOException {

        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(excellocation));

            // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
            // count number of active tows
            int totalRow = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
            // count number of active columns in row
            for (int i = 1; i < totalRow; i++) {
                XSSFRow r = sheet.getRow(i);
                String ce = r.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                if (ce.contains(testCaseName)) {
                    r.createCell(2).setCellValue(testStatus);
                    file.close();
                    System.out.println("resule updated");
                    FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(excellocation));
                    workbook.write(outFile);
                    outFile.close();
                    break;
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Object[][] getExcelDataBasedOnStartingPoint(String excellocation, String sheetName, String testName) {
        try {
            String dataSets[][] = null;
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(excellocation));

            // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
            // count number of active rows
            int totalRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            int totalColumn = 0;
            // Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            int i = 0;
            int count = 1;
            while (rowIterator.hasNext() && count == 1 || count == 2) {
                // System.out.println(i);

                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                // For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                int j = 0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    if (cell.getStringCellValue().contains(testName + "end")) {
                        count = 0;
                        break;
                    }

                    // System.out.println(sheetName+"Start");
                    if (cell.getStringCellValue().contains(testName + "start")) {
                        // count number of active columns in row
                        totalColumn = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells() - 1;
                        // Create array of rows and column
                        dataSets = new String[totalRow][totalColumn];
                    }
                    // System.out.println(sheetName+"Start");
                    if (cell.getStringCellValue().contains(testName + "start") || count == 2) {
                        System.out.println(sheetName + "start");
                        count = 2;
                        // Check the cell type and format accordingly

                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            dataSets[i - 1][j++] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            if (!cell.getStringCellValue().contains(testName + "start")) {
                                dataSets[i - 1][j++] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            dataSets[i - 1][j++] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                            dataSets[i - 1][j++] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }

                System.out.println("");
                i++;
            }
            file.close();

            return parseData(dataSets, totalColumn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to remove unwanted null data from array
     * 
     * @param data
     * @return
     */
    public Object[][] parseData(Object[][] data, int colSize) {
        // Creating array list to store data;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        // This array list will store one Array index data, every array index
        // has three sets of data
        ArrayList<String> list1;

        System.out.println(data.length);

        // running for loop on array size
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // creates a list to store the elements != null

            System.out.println(data[i].length);

            list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            // this for loop will run on array index, since each array index has
            // three sets of data
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                // this if will check null
                if (data[i][j] != null) {
                    list1.add((String) data[i][j]);
                }
            }
            // once all one array index data is entered in arrayList , then
            // putting this object in parent arrayList
            if (list1.size() > 0) {
                list.add(list1);
            }
        }
        // convert array List Data into 2D Array
        Object[][] arr2d = new Object[list.size()][colSize];
        // run loop on array list data
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            // every array list index has arryList inside
            ArrayList<String> t = list.get(i);
            // run loop on inner array List
            for (int j = 0; j < t.size(); j++) {
                arr2d[i][j] = t.get(j);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(arr2d);
        return arr2d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String excellocation = "D:\\usman data\\excel-tutorial-with-dataDrivenFramework-master\\excel-tutorial-with-dataDrivenFramework-master\\src\\main\\resources\\testData\\demo.xlsx";
        String sheetName = "login";
        ReadDataFromExcelSheet excel = new ReadDataFromExcelSheet();
        Object[][] data = excel.getExcelDataBasedOnStartingPoint(excellocation, sheetName, "login");
        System.out.println(data);
        // excel.updateResult(excellocation, sheetName, "Login Test", "FAIL");
        // excel.updateResult(excellocation, sheetName, "Registartion Test",
        // "PASS");
        // excel.updateResult(excellocation, sheetName, "Dashboard Test",
        // "PASS");
}

}
```

**I am getting the following error:**

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.dom4j.io.SAXContentHandler (file:/C:/Users/True%20Meridian/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar) to method com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$LocatorProxy.getEncoding()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.dom4j.io.SAXContentHandler
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
java.lang.NullPointerException
null
    at com.usman.ReadDataFromExcelSheet.getExcelDataBasedOnStartingPoint(ReadDataFromExcelSheet.java:130)
    at com.usman.ReadDataFromExcelSheet.main(ReadDataFromExcelSheet.java:258)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The exception returns specific line numbers for the function, but I can't tell exactly which line is failing.  It would help if you could highlight what is on lines 130 and 258.

Answer (score 0):

On `XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);` in method `getExcelDataBasedOnStartingPoint` it probably returns `null`. If it does, the name provided is not the sheet name of any sheet in the workbook. You should check for null. Like this:

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
if (sheet == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sheet with sheet name " + sheetName + " does not exist");
```

This being said, this does not exactly resolve your issue. Your main issue is, that sheet "login" does not exist in the workbook "D:\usman data\excel-tutorial-with-dataDrivenFramework-master\excel-tutorial-with-dataDrivenFramework-master\src\main\resources\testData\demo.xlsx".